# Can we remove the [zeppelin] tag since it appears to be duplicated by [apache-zeppelin]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I regularly monitor Hadoop questions and I noticed we have a [zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeppelin) tag.  However, the more widely used [apache-zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-zeppelin) tag (658 questions vs 42 questions) seems to be established one and the [zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeppelin) tag doesn't have a description.  Of the 42 [zeppelin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeppelin) tagged questions only 8 seem non-Hadoop/Spark-related but as Apache Zeppelin works with SQL and Python too the remaining 8 still seem to apply to Apache Zeppelin.

Comment: Seems like a merge + synonym is more adequate than a removal (burninate).

Comment: That would work.

Comment: Are there any other possible uses for [zeppelin]? Do people have questions about programming controllers for large, rigid airships, for example?

Comment: So [zeppelin] is really made out of lead?

Comment: @CodyGray [tag:zeppelin] + [tag:spark] = ???

Comment: Tag usage: questions regarding how to programmatically control light-emitting diodes on airships should be tagged [tag:led] [tag:zeppelin].

Comment: @Lundin do not use for programmatic control of alternating current/direct current

Comment: @Lundin: SACRILEGE!!!!!!!! :-)

Comment: @Cœur - and questions regarding fire-fighting gases used in small multi-passenger transport vehicles would doubtless be tagged `[van halon]`..?

Comment: I know only I am truly responsible for my own actions, but hopefully I can at least get some sympathy for the precious, irreplaceable hour I've just squandered trying to find band name tags.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - you will have your reward in Rock'n'Roll Heaven (where you know they've got a helluva band...). (BTW - how many did you find..?)

Comment: @CodyGray don’t forget about the smart contract library OpenZeppelin

Comment: [tag:zeppelin] was already removed/retagged by someone. I have anyway added a synonym retroactively.